# getting the start command to send a message once its task was complete - is it possible

Tags: email, batch-file, notifications, cmd

is it possible to get a command window to fire off an email when a previous task completes ??

we are using the following in a script to fire off multiple robocopy's

start cmd /T:5A /K robocopy... (thanks to msam in this thread [How can i change the colour of a command window via batch script when using the start command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349069/how-can-i-change-the-colour-of-a-command-window-via-batch-script-when-using-the) for helping us here)

what i would like to do is once the robocopy finishes and displays the summary section fire off an email or set off a different batch file so that a message could be sent to me. we have a number of copies to do over night and rather than sit there looking at them this would alert me once it was complete for me to login and start the next stage.

im not sure if it is possible or how difficult it would be to setup.

i wouldnt know where to start with this im afraid.

thanks in advanced.

jay

Comment: have you tried to invoke a BAT file that starts robocoy and fires the message.

Comment: How would I go about doing this so that the message was sent after robocopy finished. Forgive me im very new to all this

Comment: in your first BAT, instead of starting robocopy, you `start` a second BAT that just invokes (without start, and thus executing sequentially) Robocopy and sendmail.

Comment: thanks for that... if im on the same page would this mean that if i had say 4 robocopy scripts it would run one at a time and after the last one it would run the sendmail section.... if this is the case its not really what we are after... we basically have a number of scripts that run together and we need to know when that batch has finished. have i misread this... is there a chance of an example so i can get an idea

Comment: you START your bat with the robocopy script as many times as you need it to run.

Comment: Hi PA i get that thanks for the short answer.... doing this does not let all the robocopy scripts run at once. they fire one at at time until the end and then sends the email... if i have 10 robocopy commands i need them all to run at the same time and then fire the email once its completed.... is this possible

Answer (score 0):

you can

1. either append the notification in the START command

   ```
   start cmd /T:5A /K robocopy copyoptions & mailsend mailoptions
   ```
2. or prepare an intermediate BAT file that invokes robocopy and then mailsend

   ```
   @echo off
   robocopy %*
   mailsend mailoptions
   ```

   and call it

   ```
   start cmd /T:5A /K copyandnotify copyoptions
   ```

   you may START the BAT as many times as you want.

Comment: works :) bit of a messy script when there is a number of copies going but it does the job... thanks

Comment: hi there ive just tried this again and its sending the emails as its doing the copy and not after have i missed something ive put the following into a batch file and i run that, 
 
start cmd /T:27 /K robocopy.exe "C:\logs" "E:\logs" /MIR /Log:e:\logs.txt /TEE & Sendmail /smtpserver smtp.Serveraddress.com /to me@mydomain.com /from servertest@mydomain.com /subject copy Complete /body Copy is Complete

would using the powershell be better if so what would i need to do to sort it that way

Comment: it might be you have some problems when copying the command? have you tried the second option?

Comment: Hi PA your gonna have to treat me like an idiot here :) am i right in saying that i create a batch file with the first section in but instead of mailsend use sendmail and the options ive used already,, then from the command line / other batch type in the 2nd section ??? would i type copyandnotify or would i need to type something else here... is robocopy %* enough in the first part... got to admit its gone over my head, is there a sample working script that you could show me so that i can see how it works thanks & sorry total noob